# Optimal way to auto select option from select drop down after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The problem I am running into is, when the form is submitted, the user's dropdown selections are lost and I would like the dropdown menu selections to be auto selected on load, after submit (form posts to the same page as it is submitted from), based on the users drop down selections.

I was wondering what is the simplest way to use the posted `$_POST` values, from `<select>` elements to auto select the corresponding options from the select drop downs.

This is what I tried, with no success:

```
<select name="filter1" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['filter1']) ? $_POST['filter1'] : ""; ?>">
    <?php echo getFilterOptions(); ?>
</select>
```

**Note:** I'm looking for the easiest way to do this. I am open to using JQuery, JavaScript, or PHP for the solution. If possible, I would like to not hard code anything into the options, because those are auto generated using mySQL / PHP.

Comment: It does not work for some reason, values are not set.

Comment: Yes, `filter1` is SET! I don't believe you can set the default value directly from the `select` tags however. This must be done from the `option` tags.

Comment: Strike that, try doing this -> http://jsfiddle.net/d96dc/1/

Comment: LOL see, you can't set value directly from the `select` tags! ;)

Comment: Nope, I was sure you could, but you have to set the selects value with javascript, for some stupid reason just setting it in the markup does work

Comment: @adeneo your method is what I ended up using. Please create an answer for it so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Sure, added an answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
<select name="filter1">
    <option value="test1">test 1</option>
    <option value="test2">test 2</option>
</select>

<script>
    document.getElementsByName('filter1')[0].value = '<?php echo $_POST['filter1']; ?>'
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Select input values are set this way:

```
<select name="filter1">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green" selected="selected">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

with the *Green* option selected.

In your getFilterOptions function you should loop through your options and for each option compare to post value of field name *filter1*:

```
<select name="filter1">
<?php echo getFilterOptions("filter1"); ?>
</select>

<?php 
function getFilterOptions($fieldName) {

  $options = array("red" => "Red", "green" => "Green", "blue" => "Blue"); // Assuming these are your database extracted options
  $select = "";
  $isSetField = isset($_POST[$fieldName]) ? true : false;


  foreach($options AS $value => $name) {
    $select .= '<option value="' . $value . '" ' . ($isSetField && $value == $_POST[$fieldName] ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $name . '</option>';
  }
  return $select;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the `selected="selected"` attribute on the option that is to be selected. Passing `$_POST['filter1']` to `getFilterOptions` and checking it against the current option you are outputting would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try

set id in html of select and use

JavaScript to select value in drop-down-list

```
<script>
function setSelectedValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectObj.options[i].value == valueToSet) {
            selectObj.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
var objSelect1 = document.getElementById('filter1');
setSelectedValue(objSelect1, "<?php $_POST['filter1']; ?>");
</script>
```

Usage

```
setSelectedValue(objSelect1,Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the values and select=selected on the value stored in _POST:

```
<?php
$dropdownFilter1= array("Dog","Cat","Fox");
echo "<select>";
foreach($dropdownFilter1 as $selectOption){
  $select = ($selectOption == $_POST['filter1'])? "selected='selected'":"";
  echo "<option $select>$selectOption</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0):

```
$isSelected = "";
$value = $_POST['filter1'];
```

...so you need to generate the drop down something like this:

```
echo "<select id='drop-down' name='filter1'>";

for($i=0; $i<=count($dropDownValues); $i++) {

     if ($value==$i) $isSelected="selected='selected'";

     echo "<option value='$i' $isSelected >$i</option>";

}
```

... I did not test this but it should work. Obviously this is missing all the $_POST validation bells&whistles etc...